# I can't echo an echo of a mixed up string into a file

Tags: bash, echo

This line works as expected on it's own

```
(echo '@$X!'; sleep 3; echo '@$X!')
```

And I need to insert this line in a file using the following command, but it's not working. The `echo`'ed command must be executable.

```
echo "(echo '@$X!'; sleep 3; echo '@$X!') | mycmd" >> a
```

It keeps returning this error

```
sh: !': event not found
```

I understand that echoing a string between single quotes, inhibits any variable substituion or character escaping but I'm unable to apply that to solve this issue !

I **have** to do it through a command because I'll be sending it through a tool so editing the file using an editor is not an available option for me.

Comment: Note: you're either not running bash, or running it in `sh` mode (this is visible from the error message). I'm not getting that error from bash, though the `$` needs escaping (and I might have non-default options set).

Comment: I get the same error in bash as well

Comment: @Muhammad-gelbana Does it really need to be a `!`? And what happens with `a` afterwards, does it get executed as a shell script?

Comment: @patrix, yeah :), also the `$` must be appended by a character. The file being appended will be executed on each startup and it's very important to have it this way.

Comment: I'm just a bit worried that we are solving the wrong problem here. What's the greater picture you want to accomplish (i.e. why do you need to programmatically create a startup script in the first place)?

Comment: @patrix, it's a configuration script for a device that runs when the device is reset\flashed. So most of the default config is saved in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

My first thought was wrong. Explicitly quoting the bang (`!`) seems to work:

```
echo "(echo '@$'\!; sleep 3; echo '@$'\!) | mycmd" > a
```

Comment: If this worked, the command in `a` would have `@$!` in double quotes, which would be problematic.

Comment: If I switch the single and double quotes the line will be appended into the file but the `echo`ed line won't execute.

Comment: @Thor, I apologize for the confusion but I didn't state my complete problem. Based on your solution and the slight update within my question (i.e a character `X` suffixes the `$`), this should be the answer: `echo '(echo "@\$X"\!; sleep 3; echo "@\$X"\!) | mycmd' > a`. Thank you.